# What is $\lfloor 1.\overline{9} \rfloor$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have an interesting question that is not a duplicate. I have been pondering this for a while, and I would like to see what MSE's "pro" mathematicians think the answer would be.

Problem:

> What is $\lfloor 1.\overline{9} \rfloor$?

My thoughts:

There are two solutions which I believe can be applied to this problem, although I'm not sure which one is correct.

Solution 1: $1.9999...$ is $2$, and the floor function would equal $2$.

Solution 2: Floor $1.9999...$ to get $1$, which is the answer.

---

I am not sure which one is correct. Please state which solution you think is correct and why. Thanks! Max0815.

Comment: It's $2$, since $1.\overline 9=2$.  The floor function is discontinuous at integers, so the second argument is incorrect.  Or at least the way I read the second argument is incorrect...as written, there really isn't any argument there at all.  It just asserts that the answer is $1$ with no explanation.  I assume they mean that, if you truncate the decimal anywhere, then you get $1$.

Comment: $2$ is $2$ no matter how you write it, so the correct answer is obviously `solution 1`. The confusion probably lies here: `a number that by definition is the number above it`. This makes no sense, there exists no such number that is greater than itself. $2$ *is* $1.\overline{9}$, *not* `the number above it`.

Comment: But how can it not be $1$? I mean, it's still in some ways correct.

Comment: How is it correct? The number $1.9999...$ equals $2$ and has no other values. So its floor function is $2$.

Comment: The number $1.999...$ approaches $2$, but never reaches it when you look at it in some ways.

Comment: @Max0815 Wrong, because $1.9999....9\neq 1.\overline{9}=2$.

Comment: The representation of a number is not the number. The map is not the territory. Getting the two confused will cause problems like this.

Comment: @above what do you mean?

Comment: A number can't approach anything. Its not a sequence of numbers, it is one number. And it equals $2$. I'm talking about the number $1.999...$ with infinite number of $9$s.

Comment: $2-1.9999...=0.00...01$

Comment: @Max0815 No, $2-1.\overline{9}=0\,$. There exists no number $\,0.\overline{0}1\,$.

Comment: And where is the $1$ in that $0.00...01$? How many digits after the decimal point? You are confusing between finite number of $9$s and infinite number of them.

Comment: The one would be behind an infinite number of $0$'s

Comment: Also, can somebody post an answer??

Comment: Why was my question downvoted? Is there anything I did wrong?

Comment: How can you have $1$ after infinite number of zeros? If there is a $1$ somewhere then the number of zeros before it can only be finite. Saying $1$ after infinite number of zeros is the same as saying "there exists a number which is bigger than all natural numbers".

Comment: Oh...I see.....

Comment: I understand it is first hard to accept that $1.999...=2$ but it is a fact. There is a proof using sums of geometric series.

Comment: Ok. Yeah...it indeed it :(. But however, I see.

Comment: But why was my OP downvoted? Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: I don't know who downvoted it. It wasn't me.

Comment: @Max0815 I don't understand the downvote, either. In fact, I would say that yours was a well asked question. General advice around here is not worry much about random downvotes.

Comment: Thank you to all the people who answered my question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were lots of comments so I'll just conclude it shortly. If you take a number $1.999...9$ with finite number of $9$s then for sure the floor function is $1$. But if the number of $9$s is infinite then $1.999...=2$ and hence the floor function is $2$.

Comment: Mark thank you.